# Maximum CSS file size on each browser can read ? How to by pass it limited?

Tags: css, browser, size, filesize

Browsers suggest: Edge, Chrome, FireFox, Opera, Safari.

- My **debug CSS** file size is more than 10,000KB.
- Some styles cannot be applied if reach the size above.
- Safe zone (below 9,000KB)

[image]

- What is the maximum CSS file size that the browser can read exactly ?
- How to increase the maximum CSS file size that browser can read ?

> Do not mention minify / purge unuse CSS in here, I know how to do it already ! **This is for debug css file !**

Comment: Could you explain a bit  more about what you see when it 'doesn't work'? Are some styles or none obeyed? Does the file pass CSS validation? Is cache cleared? If split into two files is everything OK? Which browsers/syststems etc. i.e. what have you already tried?

Comment: - Cache is already cleared.
- Tried Edge, Chrome, FireFox, Opera.
- OS: Windows 10 pro - Version: 21H1
- Everything fine if split file (I do not desire splitting the file because it's a debug file !)
- Those CSS inside generate and auto corrected by tools (so there is no error code inside) [Checked correction and no issue: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ ]

> The only issue in here is the browser reading limited size and how to by pass it.
- Have you tried to creating an 10,000KB CSS file before ?

Comment: No, have never seen a CSS file anything like this large, it must be half a million lines long. I think I'd regard that as unmaintainable. Sorry not to be of any help!

Comment: This is not part of any spec, as far as I can tell, but rather is an implementation detail that you should not depend on. Adam Watham (creator of TailwindCSS) mentions this problem here: https://youtu.be/3O_3X7InOw8?t=21 and suggests that it is (as of March 2021) in the neighborhood of 12MB (looks like he's testing in Microsoft Edge).